# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: TDIDS not bound

Tags: jboss, jndi

I am getting the subject error. Details of `*.ds.xml` are as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources>
    <local-tx-datasource>
        <jndi-name>KHDS</jndi-name>
        <connection-url>
            jdbc:sqlserver://servername:1433;DatabaseName=mydb;SelectMethod=cursor
        </connection-url>
        <driver-class>
            com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
        </driver-class>
        <user-name>user</user-name>
        <password>pwd</password>
        <min-pool-size>50</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>500</max-pool-size>
        <query-timeout>60</query-timeout>   
        <blocking-timeout-millis>60000</blocking-timeout-millis>
        <idle-timeout-minutes>1</idle-timeout-minutes>
        <metadata>
            <type-mapping>MS SQLSERVER2000</type-mapping>
        </metadata>
    </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

The Error trace is as follows:

```
- javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: KHDS not bound
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:491)
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:499)
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getObject(NamingServer.java:505)
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:278)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:544)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:520)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at pk.com.tdi.core.db.DBManager.createConnection(DBManager.java:203)
    at pk.com.tdi.core.db.DBManager.<init>(DBManager.java:65)
    at pk.com.tdi.core.wf_1_0.facade.WorkflowServiceImpl.getCurrentStage(WorkflowServiceImpl.java:384)
    at pagecode.PolicySearchDetail.onPageLoadBegin(PolicySearchDetail.java:241)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The JNDI resource you are trying to access does not exist. Please check the resource in the server if that exists with the JNDI name you are trying to access.

Regards,